# SQL search for containing terms

Tags: sql, contains

If it possible to search in a table for records of which its name contains a search term?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the name of the table or the name of the column?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE name LIKE '%my_search_term%'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE CONTAINS(name, 'search')
```

But be aware that the LIKE statement is very expensive. If you searching through a lot of text, you might want to consider using Sphinx for exemple.

Comment: Yeah should've linked it. It's very powefull, you populate your Sphinx indexes from MySQL (for example, where i work, we update Sphinx every 2h), and after it's very simple.
There is a Sphinx client in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/book.sphinx.php
Very simple to use, and it's really faster than MySQL for text search.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. There is the `CONTAINS` predicate:

```
... WHERE CONTAINS(name, 'search-term')
```

There is also the `LIKE` operator and some DBMS allow for regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are looking for is [LIKE](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-LIKE.asp)

```
-- Get all people with phone numbers starting with 920
SELECT * FROM People WHERE PhoneNumber LIKE '920%'
```