# How do you query an array in Standard SQL that meets a certain conditional?

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery, where-clause

I am trying to pull records whose arrays only meet a certain condition.

For example, I want only the results that contain "IAB3".

Here is what the table looks like

#### Table Name:

bids

#### Column Names:

BidderBanner / WinCat

#### Entries:

```
1600402 / null
1911048 / null
1893069 / [IAB3-11, IAB3]
1214894 / IAB3
```

How I initially thought it would be

```
SELECT * FROM bids WHERE WinCat = "IAB3"
```

but I get an error that says no match for operator types array, string.

The database is in Google Big Query.

Comment: What database are you using?  "Standard SQL" does not support arrays.

Comment: You might find [LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691917/sql-search-for-containing-terms) helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.bids` WHERE 'IAB3' IN UNNEST(WinCat)
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.bids` AS (
  SELECT 1600402 BidderBanner, NULL WinCat UNION ALL
  SELECT 1911048, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1893069, ['IAB3-11', 'IAB3'] UNION ALL
  SELECT 1214894, ['IAB3'] 
)
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.bids` WHERE 'IAB3' IN UNNEST(WinCat)
```

with result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to use single quotes in sql for all strings. it should be WHERE WinCat = 'IAB3' not WHERE WinCat = "IAB3"

Comment: For reference, see [What is the difference between single and double quotes in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992314/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `unnest()`, something like this:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM bids b
WHERE 'IAB3' IN (SELECT unnest(b.WinCats))
```

However, array syntax varies among the databases that support them and they are no part of "standard SQL".

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
SELECT * FROM bids WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (WinCat, '(.)*(IAB3)+()*');
```